# Angled Post Connector

Tags: post, footings, pergola, connectors, carport

I'm looking to build a pergola like [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99402/mount-pergola-post-at-an-angle/99488).

[image]

Would a connector such as the concealed [Simpson StrongTie CPTZ](https://www.strongtie.com/retrofitpostbases_postbases/cptz_base/p/cptz) work for the posts?

[image]

The specs seem fine, what I'm worried is the footnote "Post bases do not provide adequate resistance to prevent members from rotating about the base and therefore are not recommended for non-braced, or non-top-supported installations.", though it seems this is the same for most of their connectors.

Comment: I think they are talking about free-standing posts, like... a rural mailbox post? Should be fine for your application, plenty of other structural components to prevent rotation.

Comment: I agree with the post mounted at the base and top I have used steel 1/8" plate in a saw cut and drilled for a non load bearing structure that I did not want external metal brackets on.

Comment: Might work, but my concern would be the relatively short stalk coming up from the plate. Have you considered having something bigger fabbed at a welding shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is Jason of Builderbeast.
I built this pergola, and was also not thrilled about the size of that Simpson connector. I had a larger 1/2" stainless  mount fabricated.  It extended about 12" up the column.